# Separate a value in two variables. C# .NET

Tags: c#, .net, variables

In the fllowing line I am listing "something":

```
var bbItems = _boardbookRepository.GetBoardBookItemsList(it.ItemID, AcUserProfile.Current.OrgUserId);
```

I want to separate this list by the value it.ItemID and so, if it.ItemID > 0 then will be stored in a variable or else, it will be stored in other variable.

How can I set it to be like the line bellow?

```
it.ItemID > 0 ? "variable"  : "variable"
```

Comment: "will be stored in a variable or else, it will be stored in other variable."Not clear . More over its a list..are you sure it will contain a single item ? Or you will be needing separate variables for every item in the list ;)

Comment: @TusharGupta Likely, what the OP needs is a Collection (Like array, List, or Dictionary) to store different variables but accessible through indexing. It is the indexing which can be decided by the ternary operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ternary operator you show is for assignment to a *single* variable, it is not for assignment to *different* variables.

If you want to assign a value to different variable depending on a certain condition (in your case: `it.ItemID > 0`), you probably need to store the different variables in a collection (say, `Array`, `List` or `Dictionary`) and then get the collection's `index/key` according to your condition:

Example using `List`:

```
List<string> IDs = new List<string>() {string.Empty, string.Empty};
IDs[it.ItemID > 0 ? 0 : 1] = "variable";
```

Another example using `Array`

```
string[] IDs = new string[2] {string.Empty, string.Empty};
IDs[it.ItemID > 0 ? 0 : 1] = "variable";
```

Comment: That was quiet enough for me. Thank you!

Comment: @GeorgiosDeliandreadis no problem! Sometimes heavy downvoting occur without proper explanation. But cheer up! Keep coding! ;)